# IIS 7 URL Rewrite HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: http, iis, https, url-rewrite-module

I updated  my rules and can get every redirect to work except for https://www.freertool.com/store/en  links

for example  https://www.freertool.com/store/en/freer-naams-alb081 wont work but if i remove the S on HTTPS it goes through.  I am just missing a step i believe should i create another rule to handle Https prior to loading the other rules?

```
<rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Store Redirect Store www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^www.freertool.com/store(.*)" />
                negate="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://freertool.com{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Store Redirect EN" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^en(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://freertool.com{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Store Redirect Store" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^store(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://freertool.com{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Store Redirect www and en" enabled="true">
                <match url="^www.freertool.com/store/en/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://freertool.com{R:1}" />
            </rule>     
        </rules>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are you getting an error? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I updated my details of my issue.